# RxJs - concatMap alternative that drops everything in between

Tags: rxjs

I'm trying to find an operator that behaves similarly to `concatMap`, but drops everything in between. E.g., concatMap does the following:

> - next a
> - start handling a
> - next b
> - next c
> - finish handling a
> - start handling b
> - finish handling b
> - start handling c
> - finish handling c

Instead, I'm looking for a mechanism that'll drop `b`, since `c` has already come in:

> - next a
> - start handling a
> - next b
> - next c
> - finish handling a
> - (skip b)
> - start handling c
> - finish handling c

See this gist for a more expanded example: https://gist.github.com/Burgov/afeada0d8aad58a9592aef6f3fc98543

Comment: Why it shouldn't skip also `c` when it arrives before `a` completes but it skipped `b`?

Comment: So basically the idea is: "synchronise the server with this new state of our object, but wait until the previous request completes". The latest is always the only one that is relevant, but the latest must always be handled, in order not to lose data.

Comment: at first i was thinking exhaustMap, that does ignore intermediate events, but then you would of course also lose c ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the operator you are looking for is `throttle`.

Here is a working [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-so-q-53739015?file=index.ts).  The key to making this work is setting the config object that is passed to `throttle()` which allows it to emit (and process) both the leading and trailing source emissions, but ignore any emissions in between, during the time `processData()` is running.

Here is the key function from the Stackblitz:

```
// Use 'from' to emit the above array one object at a time
const source$ = from(sourceData).pipe(

  // Simulate a delay of 'delay * delayInterval' between emissions
  concatMap(data => of(data).pipe(delay(data.delay * delayInterval))),

  // Now tap in order to show the emissions on the console.
  tap(data => console.log('next ', data.emit)),

  // Finally, throttle as long as 'processData' is handling the emission
  throttle(data => processData(data), { leading: true, trailing: true }),

).subscribe()
```

Short and sweet, and works as required except for one issue...

## Update:

That "one issue" with the code above is that when the source observable completes, `throttle()` unsubscribes from processData, effectively stopping any final processing that needed to be done.  The fix, as Bart van den Burg pointed out in the comments below, is to use a Subject.  I figure there are many ways to do this, but the Stackblitz has been updated with the following code that now works:

```
// Set up a Subject to be the source of data so we can manually complete it
const source$ = new Subject();

// the data observable is set up just to emit as per the gist.
const dataSubscribe = from(sourceData).pipe(
    // Simulate a delay of 'delay * delayInterval' before the emission
    concatMap(data => of(data).pipe(delay(data.delay * delayInterval))),
).subscribe(data => {
    console.log('next ', data.emit); // log the emission to console
    source$.next(data); // Send this emission into the source
});

// Finally, subscribe to the source$ so we can process the data
const sourceSubscribe = source$.pipe(
    // throttle as long as 'processData' is handling the emission
    throttle(data => processData(data), { leading: true, trailing: true })
).subscribe(); // will need to manually unsubscribe later ...
```

Comment: Hey, this is perfect! And very elegant and simple, great. If instead of a finishing observable, I hook it up to a Subject (which is the case in the real project), it actually works just as it should. See https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-so-q-53739015?file=index.ts. Thanks!

Comment: @BartvandenBurg - facepalm - I should have thought of a Subject!  I don't think your edit of the Stackblitz "took" - you would probably have to fork it and edit your own copy.  I edited the Stackblitz and will update the answer as well.  Good teamwork!  :)

Comment: +1 for the config in throttle that I had no idea existed. However, doesn't this behave fundamentally different from concatMap in the sense that it emits the source values rather than the values produced by the switched observable?

Comment: @IngoBürk - yes, that is true, the observable chain is unused past the call to `processData()`, as I was assuming the function consumes and uses all the data the OP was looking for.  But you are right, if there is a need to see the value actually returned from `processData()` further down the chain (inside the `subscribe()` for example, this solution would not work as-is.  @Bart - do you have need of the values returned by `processData()` such as to update a view, etc?  If so, you'll have to pipe them with `processData().pipe(/* do something */)` as they are not emitted from `throttle()`.

Answer (score 2):

This is the easiest solution I was able to make:

```
const source = new Subject();
const start = new Date();
const mockDelayedObs = val => of(val).pipe(delay(1200));

source.pipe(
  multicast(
    new ReplaySubject(1),
    subject => {
      let lastValue;

      return subject.pipe(
        filter(v => v !== lastValue),
        exhaustMap(v => {
          lastValue = v;
          return mockDelayedObs(v);
        }),
        take(1),
        repeat(),
      );
    }
  ),
)
.subscribe(v => {
  console.log(new Date().getTime() - start.getTime(), v);
});

setTimeout(() => source.next(0), 0);
setTimeout(() => source.next(1), 500);
setTimeout(() => source.next(2), 1000);
setTimeout(() => source.next(3), 1500);
setTimeout(() => source.next(4), 1800);
setTimeout(() => source.next(5), 4000);
```

Live demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-z33jgp?devtoolsheight=60

The order of actions is like this this:

```
next 0
start handling 0
next 1
next 2
finish handling 0
start handling 2
next 3
next 4
finish handling 2
start handling 4
finish handling 4
start handling 5
finish handling 4
```

So only 0, 2, 4 and 5 will be printed

This would work without the `multicast` operator as well but I wanted to avoid leaking state variables. It seems like it's not entirely possible without them so there's just one `lastValue`. This variable is used only to ignore calling `mockDelayedObs` for the same value twice after resubscribing to the same chain with `repeat()`.

Comment: It seems that when the source finalize, the observer is not notified about it...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try to use the `race` method on `b` and `c` right after performing a `mergeMap`  on `a`?

I would look like something like this :

```
a.pipe(
  mergeMap(AResult => {
     // store aResult
     return race(b,c)
  }
).subscribe(
   finalResult => {
      // final result corresponding to either b or c
   }
)
```

This would work if you have an already defined number of calls to perform after `a`.

Comment: It's not a defined number though, my example could have included the whole alphabet, where the amount of handling operations could be anywhere between 2 and 26, depending on the speed of nexts and handling duration

Comment: I'm not sure to fully understand what you are trying to do. Could you add one or two more letters in your example to be sure ? Do you want to handle the first observable and then take the first from among all of those remaining ?

Comment: I've added a more extended example in the post

Answer (score 0):

Phew, this was a hard one to crack:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yk7akk

So basically, i create 2 observables:

- immediateItems are items that can be executed immediately
- postponedItems is based on lastFinished$. It will emit the last item that was prevented from executing.

concatMap then operates on a merge of these 2 observables..

It works as described, but its not exactly an easy or straightforward method (imperative code smell). Im keeping an eye on this discussion for more elegant solutions.

Answer (score 0):

@dmcgrandle solution rewritten as an operator:

```js
export function trailingMap<T, O extends Observable<any>>(
  project: (value: T) => O
): OperatorFunction<T, ObservedValueOf<O>> {
  return (source: Observable<T>) => {
    const values$ = new Subject<any>();

    source
      .pipe(throttle(data => project(data)
        .pipe(
          tap(
            next => values$.next(next),
            e => values$.error(e)
          )
        ), {leading: true, trailing: true}))
      .subscribe(
        () => {},
        () => {},
        () => {
          values$.complete();
        },
      );

    return values$.asObservable();
  };
}
```

@Martin's solution rewritten as an operator (does not complete):

```js
export function trailingMap<T, R, O extends ObservableInput<any>>(
  project: (value: T, index: number) => O,
): OperatorFunction<T, ObservedValueOf<O> | R> {
  // return mergeMap(project, 1);

    return multicast(
      new ReplaySubject(1),
      subject => {
        let lastValue;

        return subject.pipe(
          filter(v => v !== lastValue),
          exhaustMap(v => {
            lastValue = v;
            return project(value, index);
          }),
          take(1),
          repeat(),
        );
      }
    )
}
```

Test:

```js
import { fakeAsync, tick } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { Observer, of, Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { delay, map } from 'rxjs/operators';

import { trailingMap } from '@shared/operators/trailing-map';

describe('trailingMap', () => {
  it('should skip intermediate source emissions', fakeAsync(() => {
    const source = new Subject();
    const mockDelayedObs = val =>
      of(val).pipe(
        delay(1200),
        map(value => `X${value}`)
      );

    const result = [];

    const observer: Observer<any> = {
      complete(): void {
        result.push('complete');
      },
      error(): void {},
      next(value: any): void {
        result.push(value);
      }
    };
    source
      .pipe(trailingMap(value => mockDelayedObs(value)))
      .subscribe(observer);

    // 0----1----2----3--4--------------------5|
    // \    x    \    x  \                    \
    // 0------------2------------4------------5|
    //     1200ms       1200ms       1200ms
    //

    setTimeout(() => source.next(0), 0);
    setTimeout(() => source.next(1), 500);
    setTimeout(() => source.next(2), 1000);
    setTimeout(() => source.next(3), 1500);
    setTimeout(() => source.next(4), 1800);
    setTimeout(() => source.next(5), 4000);
    setTimeout(() => source.complete(), 6000);

    tick(9000);
    expect(result).toEqual(['X0', 'X2', 'X4', 'X5', 'complete']);
  }));
});
```